# ORA-00911 invalid error thrown while executing sql query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle10g

PLease check the below code and tell me where I have mistaken. I am seeing this code from long but unable to find it.
it says ORA-00911 invalid error which means some special character has crept in the code but I am unable to track it. If i create One table at a time the script runs 
but when i run two tables script at once it gives error stating: ORA-00911: invalid character. i know this is silly doubt but sometimes due to overcoding we miss small things which others can easily find. so please help me. thanks

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT.BHUSH
(
  S_DATE   DATE,
  SUBJECT  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  FROM_ID  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  EMP_ID   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  MESSAGE  VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
  TIME     VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
PCTUSED    40
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       2147483645
            PCTINCREASE      0
            FREELISTS        1
            FREELIST GROUPS  1
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;


CREATE TABLE PROJECT.CLIENT_DETAILS
(
  CLIENTID                 VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  CLIENTNAME               VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CLIENTADD                VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
  PHONENO                  VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),
  EMAIL                    VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  REGDATE                  DATE,
  CLIENTREQUIREDDATE       VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  CLIENTREQUIREDPLATFORMS  VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  PROJECTDESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE SYSTEM
PCTUSED    40
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       2147483645
            PCTINCREASE      0
            FREELISTS        1
            FREELIST GROUPS  1
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running this as a script it's your ";". If you're using SQL*Plus you might try using "/" instead between statements.

One thing: I wouldn't be creating user tables in the SYSTEM tablespace as you're now mixing your stuff with Oracle database stuff and if you ever want to do tablespace management, you might find it's a bit trickier.